# Convert huge file to encoded string in Java without any out of memory exception

Tags: java, inputstream, encode

I want to convert huge file to encoded string in Java without any out of memory exception.
Please suggest me the best solution.

Comment: How big is the file? Why are you getting an exception? Do you have code that works for smaller files, if so, can you show it? What are you planning to do with this string? Understand that a string is stored in memory. So if the file is that big, you can impossibly hold the string in memory - it makes no sense.

Comment: byte[] byteArray = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputstream);String encodedString = Base64.getEncoder.encodeToString(byteArray);

Comment: That merely addresses the things I mentioned. Please take the time to fully answer everthing asked. Read [ask], thanks.

Comment: It's a 70 mb file but I may get multiple requests concurrently

Comment: From my controller I need to send response as json that json should contain a property and it's value should be the generated encode string.{ "encodedProperty":encodedString}

Comment: String or String buffer or String builder anything fine for me as an encoded format

Comment: I do not see any possibility to avoid holding everything in memory (unless your server supports reactive programming). So I would simply block incoming requests or delay them a bit if you are running out of space, waiting until some of the other requests have finished and you have space again.

Answer (score 3):

A java.lang.String, in java, is in memory. What you want is entirely impossible. Programming is not that simple. Your options are:

1. stream the file. As in, process the file in chunks; ensure your code does not require either `String`, nor the ability to look at any particularly specific index in the file, nor to look ahead or behind.
2. Combination of stream and chunk: Keep reading data from the file until you see some separator chunk or other indication you have one chunk of data, then process the chunk, and keep going. Ensure the input does not have any huge chunks (or define a chunk to never be larger than some manageable amount), then process the chunk, without consideration from previous or future chunks.
3. Use a RandomAccessFile, but this requires that you know the exact position of the chunk you are looking for. This gets fairly complicated.
4. Forget about all this, dump the file into a database, and interact with the database.

'I just want a string with the contents of this 10GB file without taking 10GB of memory' is **impossible**.

Comment: Encoding chunks of bytes and appending the respective encoded Strings didn't give me a proper file when I decoded the entire encoded String to a file.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a compression to a `byte[]`. Using a `new GZipOutputStream(new ByteArrayOutputStream())`. If the data can be compressed (and is not an already compressed video or such), then it might work.

Using a `String` is a bad idea, as a Charset conversion is always done, and String operation might invoke `char[]`, a `char` being 2 bytes. You might try StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1, a single byte encoding. Normally one would encode the bytes as Base64 ASCII, but that again enlarges the data by 33%.

Try something different.